# How to use bundled js in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

Is there a way to use functions from a bundled js file in blazor, since all the functions names are changed due to minification ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've managed this so far is by using SnowPack. I tried following an example by Brian Lagunas on using NPM in Blazor with webpack, but seemed to have an issue probably similar to yours. My Javascript interop failed to find the methods on the bundled and minified js file. I followed Brians Example for his js files and it worked, but for my own it didn't.
With Snowpack it worked immediately.

I documented what I did on a blog post for next time I need it:
http://littlewolfsolutions.com/blog/javascript-interop-in-blazor-web-assembly-part-4-using-npm-in-blazor/

this is however assuming you are initially using the original (unbundled) files and bundling them then trying to use the bundled file.

Comment: One workaround i found so far is to add all the functions to the window object. Something like import {someFunc} from 'someFile';   window.someFunc = someFunc; in the index.js that gets bundled. The downside of this is that all of the js functions end up in the window object.